# How do I Default the date to todays date for required field using EditForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a required property(using DataAnnotations) that defaults all the values without a ? mark after the type. it defaults to 01/01/0001. How can I make this blank or default to a certain date?

P.S I also had two int properties and they defaulted to 0. This makes no sense since I have no idea how it defaults.

Model property:
[image]

Form field:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just add a default value in the model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Job Start Date field is Required")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was actually looking to set a default inside the Razor Component area. This works as intended now.

Comment: @ChadLomax What do you mean by `inside the razor component area`? Please show me where is that area

Comment: You do this inside your Model that your form will map to. The answer here should be accepted. However, there is a typo in the answer. It's not "=Datime.Now" but instead "= DateTime.Now;"

Comment: @zaifrun Thanks for noticing the typo!

Answer (score 5):

Asides adding a default value you can override the OnInitialized blazor component method and set a default value in the component.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   request.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```